# How to run shell commands in different directory using python subprocess command?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a shell command, for e.g "ls" in a different directory from my python script. I am having issues changing the directory directly from the python code from subprocess.

Comment: What do you want to achieve can you please post some example code of what you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Subprocess "call" function can't find path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231176/python-subprocess-call-function-cant-find-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subprocess` methods all accept a `cwd` keyword argument.

```
import subprocess

d = subprocess.check_output(
    ['ls'], cwd='/home/you/Desktop')
```

Obviously, replace `/home/you/Desktop` with the actual directory you want.

Most well-written shell commands will not require you to run them in any particular directory, but if that's what you want, this is how you do it.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please update your question to include the actual code which doesn't behave like you expect.

(Of course, a subprocess is a really poor way to get a directory listing, and [`ls` is a really poor way to get a directory listing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) if you really want to use a subprocess. Probably try `os.listdir('/home/you/Desktop')` if that's what you actually want. But I'm guessing you are just providing `ls` as an example of an external command.)

Comment: Okay, to be more particular i am building a GUI in python. In the GUI i am connecting a button to a function which runs the shell command "make check" for a particular make file in a different directory. The point here is that the directory where the makefile is located is not fixed(can be anywhere in the system), so at first i am extracting the location of the directory and adding it to the variable. I still have to try the cwd command but i hope it works or is there any other easy and more efficient way to do it. Also "ls" was just an example, definitely not listing contents with subprocess.

Comment: `make -C directory check` should work too.  That is, `subprocess.run(['make', '-C', directory, 'check'])` where we assume `directory` is a variable which contains the path to the directory.

Comment: Perhaps tangentially see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 2):

To add to tripleees excellent answer, you can solve this in 3 ways:

1. Use subprocess' `cwd` argument
2. Change dir before, using `os.chdir`
3. Run the shell command to the exact dir you want, e.g. `ls /path/to/dir` OR `cd /path/to/dir; ls`, but note that some shell directives (e.g. &&, ;) cannot be used without adding `shell=True` to the method call

*PS as tripleee commented, using `shell=True` is not encouraged and there are a lot of things that should be taken into consideration when using it*

Comment: `;` is among those, too. You really want to avoid `shell=True` if you can; see [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: I agree shell=True is less than ideal. I only want to show here the range of possibilities. I actually ordered it from best to worst, however, some cases can benefit from it

Comment: Sure, it's just that you gloss over the complications. With `shell=True` you normally pass in a single string and let the shell parse it, so e.g. `ls /home/you/Desktop` will work fine. Without `shell=True` you need to split this into a list yourself; `['ls', '/home/you/Desktop']`

Comment: I always pass the string like `ls bla bla`. When adding shell True I leave it as it is, and when it's false, I add split()

Comment: Plain `split` doesn't work if your command has quoted strings which contain whitespace. There's `shlex.split()` which can handle this, and other complications; but again, perhaps your answer should spell these things out, or at least note that it's not entirely trivial to summarize the differences.