# How to implement your own command prefix in a shell?

Tags: shell, cmd, terminal

I've noticed that if you wanted to use, let's say .NET  Core, you can call it from any directory by using `dotnet` and then your arguments after that.

Now let's say I need to run my own console application from any directory possible to encrypt files, I would like to call `CryptApp --encrypt --foo`, which results into my program encrypting that file.

Normally to run my program, which is a .NET Core console app, I need to do the following: `dotnet CryptApp.dll -- --encrypt --foo`. How can I convert that into `CryptApp --encrypt --foo`?

*Note that I am not taking about a specific terminal here, because I want to know how to do this for mainly CMD (Windows) and the terminal in linux/macOS systems.*

*Also, I don't really know how to format this question title properly, so if there is someone that can get a better title, please go ahead and edit the title.*

Comment: Write a script called `CryptApp.bat` on Windows and `CryptApp` on Linux/macOS and put it in your PATH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a bash script to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054538/add-a-bash-script-to-path)

Comment: In Bash, it would be `alias CryptApp='dotnet CryptApp.dll --'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in a directory in you PATH variable named `CryptApp.bat`. Set the contents of `CryptApp.bat` to:

```
dotnet CryptApp.dll -- %~1 %~2
```

After the `CryptApp.bat` file exists in a directory in your PATH, you can use the command:

```
CryptApp --encrypt --foo
```

The contents of a `CryptApp` file on Linux depends on how the command is made available on the platform.