# How to execute from any directory Bash script that sources other Bash scripts (not using path variable)

Tags: linux, bash

I am not trying to execute a Bash script from any directory by adding the script to my Path variable.

I want to be able to execute the script from any directory using the directory path to that file ... but the file I want to execute sources other files, that is the problem.

If I am in directory `file` with two scripts `myFunctions.sh` and `sourceFunctions.sh`

`sourceFunctions.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./myFunctions.sh
echoFoo
```

`myFunctions.sh`

```
function echoFoo()
{
    echo "foo"
}
```

I can run `myFunctions.sh` and `foo` will print to console, but If I go up a directory and run `myFunctions.sh` I get error

```
cd ..
file/sourceFunctions.sh
-bash: doFoo.sh: command not found
```

Unless I changed `source file/myFunctions.sh` to `source file/myFunctions.sh` in `sourceFunctions.sh`.

So how can I source independent of my working directory so I can run `sourceFunctions.sh` from any working directory I want?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a bash script to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054538/add-a-bash-script-to-path)

Comment: how is this a duplicate? im not trying to add a bash script to a path variable

Comment: Maybe something along the lines adding *`pwd`* to the source command? Maybe pwd does not work, but $BASH_SOURCE does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/determining-path-to-sourced-shell-script ?

Comment: I added an answer, maybe not the optimal, but it works

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea.  Doesn't need to be that complicated though:

```
source `dirname $0`/myFunctions.sh
```

I often compute "HERE" at the top of my script:

```
HERE=`dirname $0`
```

and then use it as needed in my script:

```
source $HERE/myFunctions.sh
```

One thing to be careful about is that $HERE will often be a relative path.  In fact, it will be whatever path you actually used to run the script, or "." if you provided no path.  So if you "cd" within your script, $HERE will no longer be valid.  If this is a problem, there's a way (can't think of it off hand) to make sure $HERE is always an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a variable of the directory path to the script itself for the source directory

so

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./myFunctions.sh
echoFoo
```

becomes

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
source ${SCRIPTPATH}/myFunctions.sh
echoFoo
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself)

Comment: This solution is more complicated than the solution above using "dirname". Is there a situation where this solution should be prefered?