# run terminal command for all files in a folder

Tags: bash, terminal, bitbucket, dbt

I have a models folder which contains a bunch of sql files `models/mart/table1.sql`, `models/mart/table2.sql`, `models/mart/table3.sql`

I run this command manually on the terminal:

```
dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args '{"model_name": "table1"}'
```

However, instead of running it individually for each table, I want to include it in the Bitbucket pipeline. How can I modify the command such that it runs in a a loop? It should extract the tablename (filename) for all files from a specified folder (models/mart) and then run the command accordingly by replacing the model_name by the filename each time?

```
pipelines:
  custom: 
    dbt-run-default:
          - step:
              name: 'Compile'
              image: fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0
              script:
                - cd dbt_4flow
                - dbt deps --profiles-dir ./profiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

sql_dir=$1

shopt -s nullglob
for sql_path in "$sql_dir"/*.sql; do
    sql_name=${sql_path##*/}
    table_name=${sql_name%.sql}
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args '{"model_name": "'"${table_name}"'"}'
done
```

- It's a program that takes the path to a directory containing '.sql' files as a command line argument.
- The `shopt -s nullglob` prevents the `"$sql_dir"/*.sql` in the code expanding to garbage if there are no '.sql' files in the directory.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${sql_path##*/}` and `${sql_name%.sql}`.

Comment: how can I run it as a single command from my terminal? When I try, I get this: ```zsh: parse error near `do'```

Comment: @x89, it's Bash code so it can't be run from a Zsh terminal.  The question is tagged 'bash'.  The easiest way to run it as a single command from your terminal is to put it in a file, make the file executable, and put it in a directory on your `PATH`.  See [Add a bash script to path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20054538/4154375).

Comment: `zsh` can be configured to understand Bash extensions, too; but obviously, if you were asking for a Bash solution, that's what you are going to get.